# Control columns inside highlighted content

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, highlighted-content-web-part

I have created a new page where I have added a new highlighted content web part.
Inside it I have linked it to a document library.

Is there a way to control the columns inside highlighted content web part ?

I want to maybe remove Modified by and add another column

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The modern web parts often don't have as many customization options as classic partsand so if the option doesn't exist in the properties panel, then the option doesn't exist. If it's critical to have this behavior, then a developer can create a custom web part via SPFx.

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

Currently There is not an option to customize the columns shown in Highlighted Content web part.

There are some similar ideas on SharePoint UserVoice:

1. [Choose display fields on Highlighted Content webpart](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/33685051-choose-display-fields-on-highlighted-content-webpa).
2. [Enable the Highlighted Content webpart to select a default view](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/35956756-enable-the-highlighted-content-webpart-to-select-a)
   .

You can vote on these ideas or you can add your own idea over there.

You can read more about Highlighted Content web part in below article:

[Use the Highlighted content web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd).

Answer (score 0):

Just as other people said, the web part now does not support such customization. You can either vote on uservoice or try some custom solutions with code work. There is already one seems to have a pretty good toolset similar to old Content Query webpart here. Take a look at it:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-content-query-webpart

And here is a similar thread with somehow a solution you can check:[Highlighted Content Column Creation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/268219/highlighted-content-column-creation)