# How can I show author instead of editor on the higlighted content webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, highlighted-content-web-part

In my organisation we use the highlighted content webpart. We would like to delete the visibilty of the editor and show the author instead. How can I change this? My first thought was to use PowerAutomate but I can't find any information and I am very familiar with PowerAutomate yet. Any recommondations?[image]

Comment: please look at this topic https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/268838/control-columns-inside-highlighted-content

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - Now it is impossible.

There is a topic on [user voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/33685051-choose-display-fields-on-highlighted-content-webpa). You can vote for it.

As alternative you can create own spfx web part and try to reproduce the higlighted content webpart functional.