# Customize search results returned by Highlighted content webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, view-formatting, highlighted-content-web-part

I am showing a "feed" from a number of lists with a particular content type with a highlighted content web part on a modern page. The latest items from the lists are shown. To show the items I used the KQL/Query Text option of this web part.

However, the search results show by the web part is not showing the most interesting columns. It just shows `Title`, `Modified Date` and `Modified By` and those fields are the least interesting fields in this case.

Is it possible to customize which columns are displayed and how they are displayed? Perhaps in the same way as with list view formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, it is not possible to show additional columns for highlight content web part in modern experience.

There are some related UserVoice, you can check them at:

1. [Highlighted content web part -> Add custom columns in the view](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/19248568-highlighted-content-web-part-add-custom-columns)
2. [Improve Highlighted content web part to support custom content types and their custom columns](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/31767952-improve-highlighted-content-web-part-to-support-cu) - It is showing the status as "Working on it".

I will advise you to vote on these ideas.

As a workaround you can use the SPFx [Content Query Web Part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-content-query-webpart) created by community members. Using this web part you can create dynamic queries as well as you can change how results will be displayed using custom HTML/CSS. You can also enhance it as per your requirements by downloading it from GitHub.

Also there is one hack given in below link (Not tested by me). You can try it if it works for you:

[Highlighted Content Column Creation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/268219/highlighted-content-column-creation)

Comment: Interesting and useful hack! However, instead of using HCWP to create a single feed, I used the List WPs and added the lists as 5 separate pipelines, since it was just five lists.